# how to query the contacts content provider given a number

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I want to query the contacts provider in android with a given number.

I have something like this

```
            String queryString= "NUMBER='" + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress() + "'"; 
            Uri contacts = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI ;

            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                       contacts,
                       null, queryString, null,
                       null
                       );
```

then how do I go upon going to the first row? Like this?

```
cursor.getString(<how do i reference to the first row?>);
```

right?

Comment: Andrew, what version of Android are you targeting?

Comment: i am targeting 2.3.3 .. I am trying to see if the number is in contacts or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
 String strNumber= "7777777777"; 
 String queryString= "NUMBER='" + strNumber + "'"; 
 Uri contacts = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI ;

 Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            contacts,
            null, queryString, null,
            null
            );
```

Hope this help!

Comment: i am targeting 2.3.3 so the use of the people uri is depricated. Thanks though for your input! :)

Comment: See my edit. From the 2.3.3 you have to use `ContactsContract`

Comment: see my edit. what's that int for the column number? thanks for the replies!